# How do I fix alembic's "Requested revision overlaps with other requested revisions"?

Tags: alembic

I work on a team using alembic to manage db migrations. I recently pulled master, and tried to run `alembic upgrade heads`. I got the following message;

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
ERROR [alembic.util.messaging] Requested revision a04c53fd8c74 overlaps with other requested revisions 453d88f67d34
  FAILED: Requested revision a04c53fd8c74 overlaps with other requested revisions 453d88f67d34
```

I got the same message when I tried to run `alembic downgrade -1`. Running `alembic history` prints this;

```
453d88f67d34 -> a04c53fd8c74 (label_1, label_2) (head), Create such and such tables.
2f15c778e709, 9NZSZX -> 453d88f67d34 (label_1, label_2) (mergepoint), empty message
b1861bb8b23f, b8aa3acdf260 -> 2f15c778e709 (label_1, label_2) (mergepoint), Merge heads b18 and b8a
(...many more old revisions)
```

which to me looks like a perfectly fine history. `alembic heads` reports `a04c53fd8c74 (label_1, label_2) (head)`.

The only thing that looks odd to me is that my alembic version db has two values in it;

```
my_postgres=# SELECT * FROM alembic_version;
 version_num  
--------------
 a04c53fd8c74
 453d88f67d34
(2 rows)
```

The only reference I can find from googling the exception is the [source code](https://github.com/zzzeek/alembic/blob/2df9c52/alembic/script/revision.py#L623), which I'd rather not read through.

How could this situation have come about? How should I fix it? What does "overlaps" mean?

Answer (score 25):

I "fixed" it by deleting the older version number in the database;

```
my_postgres=# DELETE FROM alembic_version WHERE version_num = '453d88f67d34';
DELETE 1
my_postgres=# SELECT * FROM alembic_version;
 version_num  
--------------
 a04c53fd8c74
(1 row)
```

I can now run upgrades and downgrades. My history and heads look the same. But I still don't know why it happened, or whether there is some db state that is subtly messed up, so if anyone has a better answer please post it!

Comment: It did happen to me when I imported part of another database by accident

Answer (score 7):

For those who find this, this happened to me as well because I tried restoring my database to an older version of it without first dropping it. I believe you should only ever have one row in your `alembic_version` table with the `version_num` of whatever version your database should currently be at.

So when I restored my database and did not drop it first, rather than replacing the current version number, it added a new row. In order to fix it I had to delete the incorrect version from my alembic table (whatever the version number of the database was that I should have dropped first). ... just to give a little more context to Altair's answer.

Comment: NB it's OK to have several lines in `alembic_version` when you use alembic branches
https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/branches.html

Answer (score 3):

1. The alembic_version table should have only one row for consistency.
2. If you restore a database data from another version, restore operation WILL ADD another row.
3. After you restore the data, delete the row which was added from the
   restore operation.

**This one worked for me:**

```sql
delete from alembic_version where version_num='e69ad4aec63b';
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the last applied migration and copy revision name.
2. Delete every records from `alembic_version` table.
3. Insert the copied revision name as the only revision name (RECORD 1).
4. `alembic upgrade head`

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI some of the wording of the other comments seems confusing. I also ran into this error. The `alembic_version` table can only contain ONE ROW. There shouldn't be more than one. This row will the be the "last applied revision". So the command `alembic stamp <revision ID>` deletes the existing entry in the database and inserts the given revsion ID, without applying any changes to the database.

I had the overlaps issue because I had multiple records existing within my `alembic_versions` table ( I manually add too many records because I deleted revisions, and to my embarrassment/confusion, coming from Django  which stores ALL applied migrations, I was unsure as to why there was only revision)